# How can i make JavaFX Confirmation dialog without cancel button?

Tags: javafx, dialog

I just want to make javaFX Confirmation dialog without cancel button.

When i just made dialog without cancel button, "X" button to close the dialog does not work.
How can i make without "Cancel" button?

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, a Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");
alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");

ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("One");
ButtonType buttonTypeTwo = new ButtonType("Two");
ButtonType buttonTypeThree = new ButtonType("Three");
ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeTwo, buttonTypeThree, buttonTypeCancel);

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
    // ... user chose "One"
} else if (result.get() == buttonTypeTwo) {
    // ... user chose "Two"
} else if (result.get() == buttonTypeThree) {
    // ... user chose "Three"
} else {
    // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
}
```

In this code i want to remove

```
ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
```

to make user can choose one of "One, Two, Three" without cancel button but the "X" button to work well.

I just tried like this.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, a Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");
alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");

ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("One");
ButtonType buttonTypeTwo = new ButtonType("Two");
ButtonType buttonTypeThree = new ButtonType("Three");


alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeTwo, buttonTypeThree);

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
    // ... user chose "One"
} else if (result.get() == buttonTypeTwo) {
    // ... user chose "Two"
} else if (result.get() == buttonTypeThree) {
    // ... user chose "Three"
} else {
    // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
}
```

But when i made like this, the "X" button does not work. How can i handle this?

Comment: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

Answer (score 0):

I just made the Button invisible.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");
            ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("One");
            ButtonType buttonTypeTwo = new ButtonType("Two");
            ButtonType buttonTypeThree = new ButtonType("Three");
            ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

            alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeTwo, buttonTypeThree, buttonTypeCancel);
            alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(buttonTypeCancel).setVisible(false);

            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
                // ... user chose "One"
            } else if (result.get() == buttonTypeTwo) {
                // ... user chose "Two"
            } else if (result.get() == buttonTypeThree) {
                // ... user chose "Three"
            } else {
                // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
            }
```